# How to calculate a sum of entries (balance) efficiently in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a table "bookings":

- id int
- amount float
- user_id

A users "balance" is the sum of all bookings. After years and some users with 100k+ entries that calculation is getting slow.

I have 2 solutions in mind:

1. Create a "balance" column in "users" table and add or substruct amounts each time a booking is added
2. Create a "last_balance" column in "users" table that is updated once a year with the users balance on the 01.01. 00:00:00, then balance is "last_balance" + sum(all-bookings-since-01.01.)

The issue with 1) is that any bug or delay in the db might result in a wrong balance. Therefore I think the balance should rather be the sum of bookings than an individual number.

Is there a "right" way to calculate a users balance in any system where users hold money?

Comment: please enter sample data and desired output

Comment: Also provide your current solution / exact SQL (with `create table` statements) which you believe is too slow.

Comment: Do not use float to save amount but use decimal. `Float data types are used to store the approximate precision point. In decimal data type, we can store the exact and same precision point.`

Comment: it is important to state the scenario and usage. What can be considered "slow" for a real time, on the flight calculation, it might be negligible for a batch process or acceptable for an internal report, for example